# CSS - Styling child element if parent has ::before

Tags: html, css

I'm calling and styling a link with class 'myCheckboxLink' like this:

css:

```
table.table-custom tbody td a.myCheckboxLink {
    /* styling */
}
```

html:

```
<table id="custom" class="display table-custom dataTable">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_33" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class=" dt-checkbox" tabindex="0">
                <a class="myCheckboxLink" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="myCheckboxSpan">
                        <i class="fa fa-check fa-check-checkbox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If td.dt-checkbox has ::before ... I want a different styling for 'myCheckboxLink':

console:

```
<table id="custom" class="display table-custom dataTable">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="row_33" role="row" class="odd">
            <td class=" dt-checkbox" tabindex="0">
                ::before
                <a class="myCheckboxLink" tabindex="0">
                    <span class="myCheckboxSpan">
                        <i class="fa fa-check fa-check-checkbox" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But this is not working:

css:

```
table.table-custom tbody td::before a.myCheckboxLink {
    display: none;
}
```

How can I have a different styling if td.dt-checkbox has ::before ?

Comment: see the problem differently and you will get the answer ---> `:before` is added only with CSS ----> so there is a style applied to a class or something --> so use this class to apply the style to your element

Comment: Do you want to toggle styles when clicking the link?

Comment: I have a checkbox in the first column ... and when on mobile width the table collapses and then I want to hide this checkbox since instead I'm getting a toggle button like here https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/default.html

Comment: Do you know what exactly collapses the table? Media query? matchMedia? JS/jQ?

Comment: Take a look here: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/default.html

Comment: That's pretty broad explanation, do you expect me to read the whole page?

Comment: I'm not sure 'what exactly collapses the table' ... but I'm using DataTable and in the provided example you can see that in responsive mode the table collapses and adds this toggle button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::before` in CSSis not a state like `:hover` or `:visited`. Instead, `::before` is referring to a different element inside the element used with before - the pseudo-element.

For example, this code is changing the background for a `div` while it's being hovered:

```
div:hover{background: Red}
```

However, this code is styling a pseudo-element inside the `div`but placed before all of its childs:

```
div::before{background: Red; content: "I'm red."}
```

That's why there is **no way** to know if there's any pseudo-element with CSS. Because it's CSS creating pseudo-elements.

## Solution:

When you define a pseudo-element for the `td`, also define the style for it's childs.